# How to get abbreviations short form like 'UTC' from swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need to get abbreviations from swift. How do i get it.  `ex: Adelaide, South Australia, Australia - ACST`

Comment: @SudheerKolasani `UCT Coordinated Universal Time`

Answer (score 1):

You can do like,

Objective c:

```
  NSLog(@"timezones: %@", [NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary]);
```

Swift :

```
   print("timezones : %@",NSTimeZone.abbreviationDictionary())

    //or

     NSLog("timezones: %@", NSTimeZone.abbreviationDictionary())
```

you can refer [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimeZone/abbreviationDictionary) for more details.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: nope sir. i need abbreviations. [click here to see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations)

Comment: i tried it sir. but its returning only 48 items. any idea to get all abbreviations?

Comment: this is apple's class method, it is returning all standard timezone abbreviations. We can't manipulate it!

Comment: ahhhh okey then. thaxs for your help sir (Y)

Comment: @EricD : I have posted answer in both!

Comment: The comment was for when your answer was 95% Objective-C, you've edited since. I've recently seen your 100% Objective-C answers to Swift questions, asking the OP to "convert to Swift" (lol) and I thought it was one of those things - sorry for the mistake.